# Print tables inside the loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I want to print all the tables in the loop with one button This code of mine only prints one table please guide me.

I want to print all the tables in the loop with one button This code of mine only prints one table please guide me.

I want to print all the tables in the loop with one button This code of mine only prints one table please guide me.

With the help of JavaScript

[image]

```
<input type="submit" value="چاپ فیش" onclick="printDiv()" class="btn btn-outline-info">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div class=" bg-white mb-5">

        <table class="table table-bordered border-dark" style="font-size:14px" id="table" dir="rtl">

            <tr>

                <td colspan="2"><img src="~/img/vira.png" height="75px" width="80px" /> </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size:14px">فیش حقوقی و تسویه حساب پرسنل <br /> 
                 @item.projectName</td>
                <td colspan="2">فیش حقوقی @item.month ماه @item.yeur </td>

            </tr>


            <tbody class="bg-white ">
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2" class="table-borderless" style="font-size:12px">نام و نام خانوادگی : @item.PersonName @item.PersonFamily</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="">کد پرسنلی : @item.PersonleCode</td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="ml-3">کد ملی : @item.PersonCode</td>

                </tr>


                <tr class=" table-warning">
                    <td>اطلاعات پایه</td>
                    <td>کارکرد</td>
                    <td>حقوق مزایا</td>
                    <td>مبلغ (ریال)</td>
                    <td>کسورات</td>
                    <td>مبلغ (ریال)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>


                </tr>
                <tr class="table-secondary text-center">

                    <td colspan="1">جمع پرداختی</td>
                    <td colspan="2">@item.TotalPayment.ToString(numSpace) (ریال)</td>
                    <td colspan="1">جمع کسورات</td>
                    <td colspan="2">@item.TotalKosorat.ToString(numSpace) (ریال)</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="3"> خالص پرداختی</td>
                    <td colspan="3">@item.TotalPayable.ToString(numSpace) (ریال)</td>

                </tr>


            </tbody>

        </table>


    </div>


    <script>


        function printDiv() {
            var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
            var htmlToPrint = '' +
                '<style type="text/css">' +
                'table th, table td {' +
                'font-family:vazir;' +
                'border:1px solid #000;' +
                'text-align:center;' +
                'padding:0.5em;' +
                '}' +
                '</style>';
            htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
            newWin = window.open("");
            newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }

    </script>
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line `<table class="table table-bordered border-dark" style="font-size:14px" id="table" dir="rtl">`.

All the tables will have same `id` which is invalid html.

Instead of `id` consider adding a common `class` to all the tables, For example

`<table class="table table-bordered border-dark print-table" style="font-size:14px" id="table" dir="rtl">`

Then get all the table using the class

```js
function printDiv() {
  var divToPrint = document.querySelectorAll('.print-table');
  var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    'table th, table td {' +
    'font-family:vazir;' +
    'border:1px solid #000;' +
    'text-align:center;' +
    'padding:0.5em;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';

  divToPrint.forEach((item) => {
    htmlToPrint += item.outerHTML;
  })
  newWin = window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

Note: You may like to add `@print` in css file instead of adding style tag

Comment: Thanks, the answer was correct, but I want each table to be on one page.In this answer, half of the second table falls on the first page.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

just like @brk said, you can use var divToPrint= document.getElementsByTagName('table')